# Using LAST_N_Months:3 on CreatedDate in databaseQuery

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql

I am setting a string qryDate = 'Last_N_Months:' + x - so it could be Last__Months:3.

I create a string qryString = 'SELECT field1 FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate=: qryDate'
and then do: result = Database.query(qryString);
I get this error: Invalid bind expression type of String for column of type Datetime

I know CreatedDate = Last_N_Months:3 works so why doesn't mine work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **[`Date Literal`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)**. You need to merge it in as such. Rather than using a bind variable, you need to actually include the string so it results in your dynamic SOQL containing a **`Date Literal`**.

```
String soql = '... WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTS:' + x;
```

---

Effectively, what you had would output:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE CreatedDate = 'LAST_N_MONTHS:42'
```

But what you really want (and the above provides) is:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:42
```